# How to change which SQLite file subsonic uses?

Tags: .net, sqlite, subsonic

I have a C# application that reads SQLite databases on my clients computer. When launching the application the user needs to select which database to use. Right now the following is in my app.config to set up the connectionstring:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LasergameDB"
       connectionString="Data Source=lasergame.db"
       providerName="System.Data.SQLite"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

And this code sets up my DatabaseConnection:

```
new SimpleRepository("LasergameDB", SimpleRepositoryOptions.RunMigrations);
```

This works fine, but only for the lasergame.db file. How would it be possible to have my users select a SQLite file on startup and then create my DatabaseConnection to that file.

(I'm using subsonic 3.0.0.4 and .NET 3.5)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
string connectionString = string.Format(@"Data Source={0}", mysqlitedbfilename);
string providerName = @"System.Data.SQLite";
var provider = ProviderFactory.GetProvider(connectionString, providerName);
lasergameRepo = new SimpleRepository(provider, SimpleRepositoryOptions.RunMigrations);
```

Of course `mysqlitedbfilename` should be replaced by the full path and file name of the sqlite db to be used.